# How to remove class of element has not img tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, removeclass

I want to remove the class description when no `<img>` tag is found in all the divs with `.box1`:

```
<ul class="radio accomodation-radio">
   <li class="homeing-outer0 homeing-outer clearfix active" style="display: block;">
       <div class="box1 clearfix">
            <div class="description">
                 <p>Preis pro Person, nur Mehrbettzimmerbelegung. Sie teilen sich Hotelzimmer im Großraum Reykjavik und 2-4-Bett-Zimmer mit bezogenen Betten während der Tour.</p>
            </div>
       </div>
</li>....
```

I tried this, but that is not working:

```
$(".accomodation-radio").find(".box1 img").each( function(){      
    if ($(this).length === 0){ 
        $(this).find("div").removeClass(".description"); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use combination of [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector

```
$(".accomodation-radio .box1:not(:has(img)) div").removeClass("description")
```

```js
$(".accomodation-radio .box1:not(:has(img)) div").removeClass("description")
```

```css
.box1 .description{color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="radio accomodation-radio">
   <li class="homeing-outer0 homeing-outer clearfix active" style="display: block;">
       <div class="box1 clearfix">
            <div class="description">
                 <p>Preis pro Person, nur Mehrbettzimmerbelegung. Sie teilen sich Hotelzimmer im Großraum Reykjavik und 2-4-Bett-Zimmer mit bezogenen Betten während der Tour.</p>
            </div>
       </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `.each()` is trying to run on elemnts that don't exist - you need to pass the `.find` inside the loop like this:

```
$(".accomodation-radio").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".box1 img").length === 0)
    { 
        $(this).find("div").removeClass("description"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: You might want:  `$(this).find(".description").removeClass(".description"); ` although the end result would be the same in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".accomodation-radio .box1").each(function(){

        if($(this).find("img").length === 0)

            $(this).find(".description").removeClass("description");

    })

})
```